# Boolean Field Django Can't Migrate to Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-templates

Django Version 4.1
I have created migration in SQLite3 and want to change to Postgresql
when i connect to Postgresql i've this error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type smallint to boolean
LINE 1: ...R COLUMN "isProduct" TYPE boolean USING "isProduct"::boolean
```

this is my model

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, db_index=True, null=True)
    pic = models.URLField(max_length = 400)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    original_link = models.URLField(max_length = 400)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 1500)
    additional_desc = models.TextField(max_length = 1500,default='')
    material = models.TextField(max_length = 200, default = '')
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0)
    weight_unit = models.CharField(max_length = 4, default = '')
    color = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '')
    dimension_length = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0)
    dimension_width = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0)
    dimension_height = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places = 2, default = 0)
    dimension_unit = models.CharField(max_length = 4, default='')
    isProduct = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    furniture_location = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default='')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i've tried to change `BooleanField` to `SmallIntegerField`, `PositiveSmallIntegerField`, and `IntegerField` and the error still says the same thing

How to fix this error because this error prevent `sessions` and `contenttype` table to be migrated

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you tried to change something in Django models and the error stays the same it means you need to restart or delete the table and start migrating it. I suggest you do this
Make sure the settings.py is connected to PostgreSQL

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '<PostgreSQL_DBName>',
        'USER': '<PostgreSQL_UserName>',
        'PASSWORD': '<PostgreSQL_Password>',
        'HOST': '<PostgreSQL_HOST>',
        'PORT': '<PostgreSQL_PORT>',
    }
}
```

1. Delete/Drop database in your PostgreSQL
2. Delete all migrations in `migrations/`
3. `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. `python manage.py migrate`

**Notes
If your PostgreSQL is localhost and you're accessing from pgAdmin

1. Disabled your connection with database
2. Delete/Drop Database
3. The Database looks like not deleted by all you need to do is close the pgAdmin and open it again
4. follow step 3 and 4 above